# mainform trying to show on closing the login form

Tags: delphi

This is the *.dpr :

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}
var
  MainForm: TForm1;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Login;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Login form :

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

procedure Login;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Uses Unit1;


procedure Login;
begin
  with TForm2.Create(nil) do
  try
    Application.MainForm.Hide;
    if ShowModal = mrOK then
      Application.MainForm.Show
    else
      Application.Terminate;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Main Form :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Login;
end;

end.
```

Both Buttons are set to Modal :mrOK.
Login Form is not auto created but on the list of available forms.

The problem is this :
If you close the Login Form (without clicking the button) for a split second the Main Form shows and then it closes (and of course, the application closes as well). It happens very fast. Seems like a flicker.

How can I annulate this attempt of my main Form to try and show itself when I close the Login Form ?

Also, setting :

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;
```

does not help either ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of hiding Main Form before you show Login you should use initialize Application to start with Main Form hidden. To do that just add `Application.ShowMainForm := false` before you create main form.

`Application.Run` that executes after you close your login form will show or not show Main Form based on value of `Application.ShowMainForm` variable that is by default true. So that will introduce flicker because main form will be shown before application terminates.

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.ShowMainForm := false;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Login;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: login procedure is used by the Main Form so users can log in and log out. They can not access the Main Form directly. That is the reason for hiding it in the first place. ps the suggested way does not eliminate the Main Form in trying to show.

Comment: Then leave Application.MainForm.Hide in Login procedure, just skip showing Main Form from startup.

Comment: @ Dalija Prasnikar I do not understand you well...Main Form is not shown on startup. It is created but not shown since login procedure hides it.

Comment: That is because ShowMainForm variable that is true by default triggers showing main form in Application.Run before application terminates.

Comment: So I do : Application.ShowMainForm := false; in project source after login ? It seems it eliminates the flicker...

Comment: In general, this approach is bad design. If you don't want the user to see `MainForm` then simply don't create it in the first place. If `Login` fails, you could just Exit the app immediately and not even call `Application.Run`. If `Login` needs to use code from `MainForm` then that code should be in `Login` itself, or at least moved to another class/unit outside of `MainForm`. `Login` and `MainForm` should not know about each other.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In general, yes design could be better. OP wants to have ability to log on and off when MainForm is running, so this complicates things a bit more.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think if you don't create the main form and just create the login form without `Application.CreateForm(...)`, and `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := true`, the login form does not have a taskbar icon.

Comment: @ventiseis if the Login form needs to be on the Taskbar, it can override `CreateParams()` to enable that behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Turn your Login procedure into function and change the main code:

```
    program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}
var
  MainForm: TForm1;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  if Login then
    begin
      Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
      Application.Run;
    end
  else Application.Terminate;
end.
```

I don't see, what you are checking in you login form. I think you should just return TRUE (login passed) or FALSE as the result, instead of trying to manipulate with other forms.